# how to display selected image from a gridview to its full size on screen

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am developing an application that has a grid view of images in it. I want to display the image on full screen when user selects an image from the grid view. Can any one please help..thank you

Comment: You can start new activity onItemClicked() of gridview, pass the image to new activity via Intent and display it in next activity's Imageview. also set the theme of next activity as fullScreen.Notitlebars from menifest file